# Convert MySQL Date to long format date

Tags: c#, mysql

I am retrieving data from MySQL database and one of the columns is a `date` type column.

MySQL stores dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

I want a date such as `2014-10-20` printed out as `20th October, 2014`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'%D %M, %Y'` format to convert your date to desired format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-20','%D %M, %Y')
FROM table
```

[*DATE_FORMAT*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

[*DEMO*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/46892)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting string from database then consider using **[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** function in MySQL to format your date into desired format

Comment: Accepted M Khalid Junaid's answer because it was more explanatory. You get an upvote though. :)